# Spring Autowiring giving NPE. not manually creating beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My service classes in my spring MVC program are still null upon running the application.  Both classes are @Service and have @Autowired in the controller class but are still null.  I've browsed around for a few days and all I've found is 2 causes, neither of which ( I believe) apply to my circumstance.

Spring boot app trying to create a discord bot, autowiring not working in controller or Junit test (NPE upon execution, and variable shows null while debugging).

Driver class:

```
package com.deth;

//imports
@SpringBootApplication
public class DethBotApplication {


    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DethBotApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private static BotCommandListener botListener;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SpringApplication.run(DethBotApplication.class, args);


        try {
            JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT)
                .setToken(TOKEN)
                //.addEventListener(command controller)
                .addEventListener(botListener)
                .build(); //starts listening in discord server.
```

Relevant controller code:

```
package com.deth.controller;
//imports
@Component  
public class BotCommandListener extends ListenerAdapter {


        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BotCommandListener.class);

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("raidAdminService")
        private RaidAdminService raidAdminService; 

        @Autowired
        private RaidRosterServiceImpl raidRosterService;

        @Autowired
        private RaidAttendanceService raidAttendanceService;

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
            JDA jda = event.getJDA();

            String msg = event.getMessage().getContentDisplay();
            if(msg.startsWith("!")) {
                String command = "";
                if(!msg.contains(" ")) {
                    command = msg;
                } else {
                    command = msg.subSequence(0, msg.indexOf(" ")).toString();
                    logger.trace("possible command: " + command);
                }
                try {
                    switch (command) {
                    //raid leader commands
                    case "!open":
                        raidAdminService.createRaid(event); //NPE here
                        logger.trace("!open detected");
                        break;
```

raidAdminService:

```
package com.deth.service;
//imports
@Service("raidAdminService")
public class RaidAdminServiceImpl extends CommandInfoService implements RaidAdminService {

    String intRegex = "[0-9]+";

    @Override
    public void createRaid(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

package structure:

- com

  - deth

    - DethBotApplication
    - Controller

      - DethBotCommandListner
    - Service

      - RaidAdminService (interface)
      - RaidAdminServiceImpl (class)
        ....

while program is up & running, send "!open" in discord server, correctly hitting the switch statement and trying to call createRaid method, but RaidAdminService wasn't autowired so its calling the method on null.

Comment: What part of `new BotCommandListener()` isn't manually creating a bean?

Comment: even taking off @Component from BotCommandListener class (to stop it from being turned into a bean?) still has the others set as null, so I'm under the impression that isn't the issue.

Comment: But that's the opposite of what you want. You need BotCommandListener to be a bean. Now you are creating it yourself, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: updated code shown in driver class and now the app fails to start up because the BotCommandListener is null instead of being autowired

Comment: Now it's null because it's static, it's not gonna work. Make it instance variable or extract it to another class.

Comment: If you create somethin with `new` then injections in that something wont work, nor it will be available for injection anywhere. There is no magic.

Comment: extract to another class as in extend it in my project and use that? not familiar with that term.  And making botListner not static shows this error 
```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field botListener
```
Thats why i made it static.

Comment: Convert to constructor injection, and your problem (and what you need to do) will become immediately apparent. (And the proper solution to that error is almost always to make the context non-static, not to staticize things that shouldn't be.)

Comment: if you want to run something after the application has been started either use a `@Configuration` annotated class with a `@Bean` annotated method, or create a `@Component` with a `@PostConstruct` method, or implement a `CommandLineRunner` or an `ApplicationRunner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at that :

```
@Autowired
private static BotCommandListener botListener;

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    SpringApplication.run(DethBotApplication.class, args);
    try {
        JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT)
            .setToken(TOKEN)
            .addEventListener(botListener)
     //...
    }
```

You annotate `@Autowired` a static field while Spring doesn't inject bean in static fields (but only in instance fields).
Your problem is indeed very common : you want to perform some tasks in the main() of the Spring Boot application class that depend on some beans.
The right approach is using the [`@PostConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation. A method annotated with that is (automatically) executed once the dependency injection was performed on the current bean : here the Spring Boot Application.
It would give :

```
@Autowired
private BotCommandListener botListener;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){    
    JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT)
        .setToken(TOKEN)
        .addEventListener(botListener)
        .build(); 
       // ...    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think issue is in your DethBotApplication class. you can't autowire there. main class need to be executed first. after that app will look for @Componet, @Service, @Controller... annotations. below code might fix your issue.

```
package com.deth;

//imports
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DethBotApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DethBotApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DethBotApplication.class, args);
        BotCommandListener botListener = context.getBean(BotCommandListener.class);
        try {
            JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT)
                .setToken(TOKEN)
                //.addEventListener(command controller)
                .addEventListener(botListener)
                .build(); //starts listening in discord server.
```

Answer (score 0):

You instantiated the object manually, so Spring doesn't know about that bean. That's why your @Autowired field is null.

Spring boot has to load primary class first, then continue to the injected bean through these class.

Answer (score 0):

Extend either an ApplicationRunner or CommandLineRunner class

```
package com.deth;

//imports
@SpringBootApplication
@Component
public class DethBotApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DethBotApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private /*static*/ BotCommandListener botListener; // i remove "static" here

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SpringApplication.run(DethBotApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String args) {
        try {
            JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT)
                .setToken(TOKEN)
                //.addEventListener(command controller)
                .addEventListener(botListener)
                .build(); //starts listening in discord server.
    ...
```

The key here is (as other answers point out) @Autowired only works if it is a @Component and not "static".